# Remover tag de comentário e seu conteúdo em Beautifulsoup 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Como faço para remover a tag de comentário  junto com o conteúdo dela com o bs4 ?

```
<div class="foo">
A Arara é um animal voador.
<!-- 
<p>Animais
Nome: Arara
Idade: 12 anos e 9 meses
Tempo de Vida: 15 anos
-->

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução simplificada baseado na resposta da pergunta [How to find all comments with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139332/10706802)

Primeiro importa o BeautifulSoup com os métodos necessários.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
```

Segundo, utilize o código abaixo para extrair os comentários

```
for comments in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    comments.extract()
```

Answer (score 2):

Baseado nas respostas da pergunta [Beautifulsoup 4: Remove comment tag and its content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23299557/1452488), você pode utilizar o método [`extract`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) para remover um item da árvore. Para saber se o item é um comentário, basta verificar se é uma instância de `bs4.Comment`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html = """<div class="foo">
A Arara é um animal voador.
<!-- 
<p>Animais
Nome: Arara
Idade: 12 anos e nove meses
Tempo de Vida: 15 anos
-->

</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', class_='foo')
for element in div(text=lambda it: isinstance(it, Comment)):
    element.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

A saída será:

```
<div class="foo">
 A Arara é um animal voador.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira apenas o content da `div foo`:

```
div = soup.find('div', class_='foo')
print div.text
```

**Resultado**

A Arara é um animal voador.

Answer (score 1):

Esta solução utiliza List Comprehension.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
[x.parent.decompose() for x in soup.find_all(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, Comment))]
```